# Serve Ionic 5 Cordova application over HTTPS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, https, stripe-payments

Is there a way to provide Ionic 5 (Cordova) application over https ?

I work with stripe and I need to implement Stripe.js.

When i serve my application with :
`ionic serve --prod`
I have the following warning :

`v3:1 You may test your Stripe.js integration over HTTP. However, live Stripe.js integrations must use HTTPS.`

Is there a way to serve a Ionic 5 with cordova application in order to use Stripe.js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible to use HTTPS. There's [a thread with useful details in the Ionic forums](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/https-for-the-app-server-protocol-instead-of-capacitor-on-ios/200116) about why this isn't a viable approach.

However, Stripe.js specifically allows `file://`, `ionic://`, and `httpsionic://` protocols, so using one of those should allow your app to work in production without issue.

Comment: Should i specify something to get an ionic or httpsionic protocol running on my app ?

Comment: If you're using Capacitor you can [configure `androidScheme` and `iosScheme` in the configuration file](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config).  If you're using Cordova [see the Ionic Cordova plugin readme for more information](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview#scheme).

Comment: It states here in the Stripe documentation for the Apple Pay button that it must come from https:// which is not possible in Ionic. https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button#html-js-prerequisites @JustinMichael have you got a reference for Stripe accepting those other urlSchemes?

Comment: I see file://, ionic://, and httpsionic:// are in the code here: https://js.stripe.com/v3/  can anyone confirm if these work as Stripe support are unsure.

Comment: Those three protocols will work for things like the Stripe Card Element, but not Apple Pay. For the Stripe Payment Request Button/Apple Pay to work the page must be loaded with HTTPS using a valid certificate; this is a security measure Apple has in place and cannot be bypassed.

Comment: @JustinMichael That is a shame so it appears there is no way to use Apple pay via elements from an Ionic app.  I guess I will need to look at the Capacitor stripe plugin next to see if it is possible to implement Apple pay.